# Can't find the syntax issue with this Ansible playbook

Tags: syntax, ansible

I'm attempting to run an Ansible playbook and I can't find out, through documentation or by looking at examples, what is wrong with my playbook.

`---
 - hosts: all
   sudo: yes
   pre_tasks:
     ignore_errors: True
   tasks:
     command: sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev python-pip
     command: sudo pip install caravel
     command: fabmanager create-admin --app caravel
     command: caravel db upgrade
     command: caravel init
     command: caravel runserver -p 8088
   - copy: src=../zika.db dest=zika.db
     failed_when: false`

I've been chasing my tail and I don't understand this error:

`The offending line appears to be:`

`---`

`- hosts: all`

```
  ^ here
```

Comment: As a side note, you should be using the [apt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_module.html) and [pip](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/pip_module.html) modules instead of `command` with the respective commands.  And if `caravel runserver -p 8088` is a command that hangs until the web server quits, you'll probably be unhappy having that in `command` (you want to create an init/upstart/systemd file for it).

Comment: In addition to the syntax errors, there are a few best practices issues. `sudo` is now deprecated. Use `become` instead. Also, using `ignore_errors` as the only thing in pre_tasks does not make sense. That should either be an option for the playbook, or for a specific task. It's also advised not to use this at all if you can find any way to avoid it. You are also using sudo in your command strings when you are already using it at the playbook level, making it redundant, and as was already covered, you should not use the command module when there is a more specific module available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command` is a task, and `tasks` is a list, so you should prefix every task with a dash.

```
tasks:
  - command: ....
  - command: ....
  ....
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Not sure why I missed this.